# Issue with pushd/popd and rebooting

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I write the following powershell, which create a bat installer for all drivers from a selected folder, and then should restart the pc.

```
New-Item C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat

Add-Content C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat -Value '

pushd C:\Tools\Drivers\

forfiles /p DellLatitude3450 /s /m *.inf /c "cmd /c pnputil -i -a @Path"

rmdir /s /q "C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450"

rmdir /s /q "C:\Tools\Drivers\Elevate"

del /f "C:\Tools\Drivers\Elevate.zip"

del /f "C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat"

shutdown /r /t 15

popd

'
```

The bat generated is working great, except for the reboot.

I tried to do the same only creating the bat with **shutdown** and it works, so I'm missing something related with pushd/popd.

Comment: you say it works except for the reboot ... then you say it works with `shutdown` ... then you say it must be something related to pushd/popd. ///// to me, at least, that does not make any sense at all. [*frown*] ///// plus, the pushd/popd you are running is in the BAT file ... and that is not powershell. why on earth are you mixing the two? powershell seems able to do everything in your BAT file without the need for a BAT file.

Comment: The bat is working(forfiles-pnputil) except for the shutdown. I'm using PDQ to deploy this, so I can't run the bat as admin physically in each machine. That's why I create a bat, which I run elevated with Elevate.exe from Winability Soft.

Comment: OK - so it's working great, except for the reboot. What does it do that you don't expect it to do? Not execute the `shutdown`? Perhaps executing `START shutdown...` may accomplish the shutdown. Perhaps it's stopping after the `del /f` since the containing directory has been deleted. If you are executing a `shutdown` what's the point of `popd`? Perhaps a `timeout /t -1 /nobreak` after the `sutdown` mat assist? (I haven't tried this...)

Comment: @ChristianGallelli - the answer by michael_heath shows where the problem is. [*grin*] i am quite embarrassed that i completely missed that ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the file creation. Had to add `-ItemType 'file'` to `New-Item`, else I got a prompt to enter *type*.

**Main issue**:

You are deleting the batch-file before the `shutdown` command is supposed to execute. Move the delete line down to the bottom of the batch-file code. That should then allow the `shutdown` command to execute as deleting the batch-file before it reaches the end, will immediately end the batch-file.

The code tested with the batch-file creation:

```
New-Item C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat -ItemType 'file'

Add-Content C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat -Value @'

pushd C:\Tools\Drivers\

forfiles /p DellLatitude3450 /s /m *.inf /c "cmd /c pnputil -i -a @Path"

rmdir /s /q "C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450"

rmdir /s /q "C:\Tools\Drivers\Elevate"

del /f "C:\Tools\Drivers\Elevate.zip"

shutdown /r /t 15

popd

del /f "C:\Tools\Drivers\DellLatitude3450.bat"

'@
```

Note: I added here-doc syntax as mentioned at [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#here-strings) even though the single quotes alone seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, just tested and works perfect! The first version of this ps/bat don't have a reboot in it, so I completely forget about the bat deleting itself before the shutdown.

Comment: Good spotting, michael!